# Ipython notebook : Name error for Imported script function

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, nameerror

I have two scripts `sources.py` and `nest.py`. They are something like this

sources.py

```
import numpy as np
from nest import *

def make_source():
    #rest of the code

def detect():
    Nest = nest()
    Nest.fit() 

if __name__=='main':
    detect()
```

nest.py

```
import numpy as np
from sources import *

class nest(object):

    def _init_(self):
        self.source = make_source()

    def fit(self):
        #rest of the code
```

When I run the script like `python sources.py` It works fine.

But in the Ipython notebook environment if I do the following

```
In [1]: from sources import *

In [2]: detect()
```

I am getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e9c378341590> in <module>()
---->  detect()

C:\sources.pyc in detect()
--> 7 Nest = nest()

C:\nest.pyc in _init_()
--> 7 self.source = make_source()

NameError: global name 'make_source' is not defined
```

I am confused about why this is occurring. Can you give me an insight on how it is different in both cases and how to solve this ?

Comment: `'_init_' != '__init__'`. You have two files circularly `import`ing from each other. Where's the code you're actually running? Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *actually works* and replicates the issue. Why don't you combine them into one script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I will try that. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that there is a difference between

```
import something
```

and

```
from something import *
```

concerning namespaces.

If you have recursive imports its better to never do "from something import *" or "import something as someotherthing"

You get a full explanation here:

[Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)